# Remove Role from AccountUser with SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

is there a way to remove a Role from a user using the Marketing Cloud SOAP API? I've retrieved the AccountUser object with the corresponding Roles, I remove the specific Role from the array and make an Update to that user and it's Roles. 
I get a successful response from the API but when I go check in Marketing Cloud the user still has the role I was trying to remove.

Any insights or past experience is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share teh soap enevelope you are using to update the accountuser object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually was able to do this based on the previous response provided, here's the SOAP body:

```
<soap:Body>
        <UpdateRequest
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Objects xsi:type="AccountUser">
                <Client>
                    <ID>[[MID]]</ID>
                </Client>
                <UserID>psapirasdasd.devsutd</UserID>
                <Roles>
                    <Role>
                        <ObjectID>[[Role.ObjectID]]</ObjectID>
                        <AssignmentConfigurations>
                            <AssignmentConfiguration>
                                <AccountUserId>[[User.ID]]</AccountUserId>
                                <AssignmentConfigureType>RoleUser</AssignmentConfigureType>
                                <IsDelete>true</IsDelete>
                            </AssignmentConfiguration>
                        </AssignmentConfigurations>
                    </Role>
                </Roles>
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </soap:Body>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code, I am trying to do the opposite - assigning a custom role to a user. I can't figure out how to do it. Do you mind sharing where do you find the fields name for 'AssignmentConfiguration'?

Answer (score 1):

Use following soap request to remove role at business unit level:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
 <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>Configure</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:1f56f49d-3edf-4782-99ff-9889d9b88a4a</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:To>https://webservice.{{stack}}.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</wsa:To>
    <fueloauth>[ACCESS_TOKEN]</fueloauth>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <ConfigureRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Action>assign</Action>
            <Configurations>
              <Configuration xsi:type="Role">
                   <!--*****ROLE ID*****-->
                   <ObjectID>[ROLE_ID]</ObjectID>
                         <AssignmentConfigurations>
                             <AssignmentConfiguration>
                                <AccountUserId>[USER_ID]</AccountUserId>
                                <BusinessUnitId>[MID_HERE]</BusinessUnitId>
                                <AssignmentConfigureType>RoleUserBusinessUnit</AssignmentConfigureType>
                                <!--TO DELETE ROLE FROM USER AT BUSINESSUNIT MARK TRUE -->
                                <IsDelete>true</IsDelete>
                             </AssignmentConfiguration>
                          </AssignmentConfigurations>
            </Configuration>
        </Configurations>
    </ConfigureRequestMsg>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: Thank you! When I perform that request I get: <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
 But the change is not reflected in the UI.

Comment: @patosapir this request is for removing roles assigned at Business Unit level and not directly assigned to the user. Please check how role was assigned.

Comment: has anyone figured out how to RETRIEVE roles that were assigned like this?
getting the accountUser object just returns global roles

Answer (score -1):

**Use below request payload to remove/add role to the accountuser**

```
<soap:Body>
            
            <UpdateRequest xmlns=\"http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI\" xmlns:ns2=\"urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com\">
            <Objects xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"AccountUser\">
            <Client>
            <ClientID>[[ClientID]]</ClientID>
            </Client>
            <UserID>[[Accountuser.userid]]</UserID>
                   
            <Roles>

                       <Role>
                                    <ObjectID>[[ROLE.ObjectID]]</ObjectID>
            
            <AssignmentConfigurations>
            <AssignmentConfiguration>
            <AccountUserId>[[Accountuser.ID]]</AccountUserId>
            <AssignmentConfigureType>RoleUser</AssignmentConfigureType>
            <IsDelete>[[if true will be deleted/removed from user. if false assign the user.]]</IsDelete>
            </AssignmentConfiguration>
            </AssignmentConfigurations>
            
                                </Role>
                            </Roles>
            <DefaultBusinessUnit>[[BusinessunitID]]</DefaultBusinessUnit>
            </Objects></UpdateRequest>
            
                </soap:Body>
```